# I want to apply function to each row of a table in Power Query M and have list as result

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table, say

```
ttt = Table.FromRecords({
        [OrderID = 1, CustomerID = 1, Item = "Fishing rod", Price = 100.0, Shipping = 10.00],
        [OrderID = 2, CustomerID = 1, Item = "1 lb. worms", Price = 5.0, Shipping = 15.00],
        [OrderID = 3, CustomerID = 2, Item = "Fishing net", Price = 25.0, Shipping = 10.00]
      }),
```

I need to have a total sum Price*Shipping. I can do it like that

```
result = List.Sum(Table.AddColumn(ttt, "TempColumn", each [Price]*[Shipping])[TempColumn])
```

Question is: can I get rid of "TempColumn" and make a list at once.

Comment: try with: Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStepName", "Custom", each [Price]*[Shipping])

Comment: I want to get rid of AddColumn, because actually I don't need a new column in a table, I need just this new series

Comment: Can you share two screensho.. 1. Your current table, 2. How you wants your data.

Comment: I have ttt, I want to get result. But I don't want to use AddColumn

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.
The function I need is

```
Table.ToList(table as table, optional combiner as nullable function) as list
```

instead of

```
result = List.Sum(Table.AddColumn(ttt, "TempColumn", each [Price]*[Shipping])[TempColumn])
```

I will do

```
result = List.Sum(Table.ToList(ttt, each [Price]*[Shipping]))
```